# In how many ways can you order in line the letters of the words $AAAABBBBBCCDE$ such that

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you order in line the letters of the words $AAAABBBBBCCDE$ such that none of the substrings: "$DE$" or "$ED$" appear in the beginning or in the end?
I was thinking - take all the combinations without limitations: $\frac{13!}{4!5!2!}$ and subtract all the words that start with "$ED$" : $\frac{12!}{4!5!2!}$ and then all the words that start with "$DE$" and then the words that end with "$ED$" and then the words that end with "$DE$"... And my answer was: $\frac{13!}{4!5!2!} - 4\cdot\frac{12!}{4!5!2!}$
Is it correct or am I missing anything?

Comment: I think you wrote down the wrong letters or calculations because there are 12 letters and there don't exist exactly four of any kind.

Comment: Yes there was one A missing. I edited my question thanks

Answer (score 3):

Total words are $\frac{13!}{2!4!5!}$.

Beginning with $ED$ is $\frac{11!}{2!4!5!}$. The same for $DE$. Thus, total of words satisfying conditions is $\frac{13!}{2!4!5!}-4\frac{11!}{2!4!5!}$